# IE not showing whole text from topojson - just 2-3 words

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, text, browser

I have big browser issue. In my project I need all browser working, but somehow the IE is just showing 2 and a half word. Look at this **jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/5uc17jwr/3/**

In Firefox and Chrome it's working. So it's a IE issue. I have the latest IE 11. Can someone tell me why it just happens to IE and also for what reason.

As you can see the code is printing text on lines.

### 1. idea

Could it be because the direction is negative? So the IE is just able to sure text going from left to right? But that's stupid =/ and why working in Firefox and Chrome?

Well I don't know why the third one is not completely displayed and the following are also not displayed. Some huge IE bug I think. If someone has an idea, let me please know. But from here I think I won't support IE anymore in my project and just continue =)

Btw: also tested with other lines and text, it is the same, always the third word, even tho the third one is NOT negative...

### 2. idea

Bringing the defs as first element bringing also no change.

Comment: Please show us the relevant source code.

Comment: Yeah sure but I cannot directly links to it with http, don't know why. sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently a bug. Microsoft is working on it:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1120262