# Loading a huge image (5mb) into svg background leads to pixelation and performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, svg, d3.js

I have some issues with **pixelation** and the **performance** of SVG background images together with D3.js.

You can already see a running example here: http://arda-maps.org/ages/first/ Please don't share until it's still Alpha. Thank you.

### Example

So let's take the **trees** as an example. This is how they should look like later in the browser as well:
[image: Tree image]

And as you can see, they might not be in the best quality but you can just hardly see any pixel. So I use this picture (~5mb) and as you can see in the link above when you click on the lab icon(on the bottom) and wait some seconds...you can see them there as well.

Alright, but if you zoom in you can see pixels. And it feels (compared to the vector view) very laggy and the performance drops immense. Here a view of that area on the website:
[image]

I also mentioned that Chrome nearly crashes before he did not yet finish the background risizing or whatever. But in Firefox it runs pretty well. So please test it in Firefox if possible.

**Another subissue** is that at least in Firefox in the zooming step 7 to 19 you don't see the image background. But in vector view all is fine. And since I do not change anything, this is another issue. But I couldn't find out a reason for this =/

### Alternatives

I know I could use tile image graphics. But these are hard or maybe even not possible to use in combination with a vector view at least in D3.js. I know Google Maps and others are successfully doing it. But they don't use data from a topojson like I do for instance.

In the end I would like to have a map that can be viewed in vector and image view. I'm also open for any creative/quaint idea =)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 5mb are too much for browser. I now tested it with **50%** of width and height. So the picture is now just **2,33mb** big.

And as you can see, it **works now** in Firefox and Chrome and the picture is loading in about 2 seconds. The performance is also okay.

But for sure I cannot zoom that much into the map anymore, otherwhise it get very pixeled. So I capped it at zooming 7x.

So the only other solution would be tiling images, but that would be way to hard to do for this project. And as I said this will kill the soft zooming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question but performance wise if you have deep hierarchy tree in SVG, you should consider using html5 canvas instead since it's much more performance efficient. It feels from your question that's the main issue. Maybe it's not the best solution for you but I think you should read up on what best suits you.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh552482.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-consider-svgs-instead-of-canvas/ for pros and cons between SVG and canvas. Microsoft Virtual Academy also has a chapter for this as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well the SVG things are working fine, as you can see. It is just the PNG background image I have questions about =) so that does not matter if I take canvas,svg,html5 or whatever I believe =) And could you explain what especially you don't understand? I mean does it not lag for you? And when zooming in all is high quality?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Microsoft Edge (Project Spartan) right now and I have no problems what so ever actually :) Unfortunately I don't have any other browser installed atm. I understand your question better now, thanks!Maybe I'm a bit stubborn but please read  the chapter "Canvas Charting/Graphing Scenarios" in the first link I gave. I really think you should compare SVG vs Canvas, if only with rendering the background image (zoom in/out). Canvas is better suited if lot of motions, elements and re-rendering, and your map isn't that static :)

Comment: Well your articles also tell that for maps it's best to take SVG. Correct me if I'm wrong. But anyway, for sure Canvas would be better for images. I read from the articles. But let's see if mixing both technologies working out well. Do you have any tips on this? And maybe you have soon something else then Spartan? And btw does Spartan show the Labels correctly? I ask because in the last IE version there is a huge bug, that is not fixed since 4 months... thx

Comment: Yeah I know, it's not a clear "use this or that" unfortunately. I downloaded Firefox and the labels are gone for Microsoft Edge I see now when comparing :/

Comment: So that issue als exists in the "new" Edge. Haha Microsoft ;) Here a link to that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210527/ie-not-showing-whole-text-from-topojson-just-2-3-words

Comment: Puh just checked the canvas thing. But not easy to mix them. Because i need the path of the svg to be taken by the canvas object. Maybe you have a tip for this?

Comment: Well I tested out some things now. So first thing is that canvas cannot handle pictures that are bigger than 4000 pixels, width or height does not matter. The other downside is that I need a special canvas environment. If I place it into a svg object it is not shown anymore. But at the end I need the canvas to be zoomable, so somehow it needs to be into the d3 zoom events, so in the already existing objects. Not quite sure how this could work wihout putting it there. But if I put it there I don't get the difference to a usual svg background. I think I open a new question on this...