# Performant ways of loading a huge image into the background of a D3 map

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

This question is concerning a previous one: [Loading a huge image (5mb) into svg background leads to pixelation and performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002398/loading-a-huge-image-5mb-into-svg-background-leads-to-pixelation-and-performan)

The image is **~5 MB** big and **20000 x 11596** pixels.

Here I would like to know which alternatives there are to load a huge PNG image into the background. I already tried several things. Maybe I used them in the wrong way but at the end I need this image somehow in the zoom object of D3.js. That is most difficult part of all I believe. To load an image into the overall background is very simple indeed. But having it zoom- and drag-able is way harder. As you can see from the link above I already managed it but the performance was miserable.

So currently I have a "sometimes" running method with a svg background. But as you can see on the link above and visiting the website, it does not work right now. But the reason for this is I, believe, that the image resolution/size is too high. Some days ago it worked with the same code, very strange. So a svg background is no solution. And I already **tested** some other things:

- loading an image to a **img** environment within the svg object - that did not show anything, I think the reason is because in svg you can just use **image** or **xlink:href**
- loading html5 with **canvas**, showing the picture but not changing when zooming
- loading image with **CSS**, did not work in the svg environment

So nothing helped or worked as intended. As I said I have some special **requirements**:

- the image is about 5 MB big
- the image is just another presentation of the map, so it shall just be loaded when the button on the bottom is clicked
- at the end there are 3 images for each map a different, so it need to be possible to change it at runtime
- the image shall be resized and dragged by the usual d3 events/mouse interactions
- the map with the image shall be wit ha good performance, like the vector-based one

So the **questions** I have right now are:

- which solution would be the best for my case
- how to get it working with the zooming events
- or maybe how to improve the current solution wth svg background

And I could also use tile images for sure. But I don't want zooming steps. I really would like to have a map that does not need to reload images if possible.

Thank you.

Btw here the image that shall be displayed: http://arda-maps.org/ages/pics/map/ages/firsthigh.png (needs some time for loading...)

Comment: I think browsers might not be made for 5MB images, regardless of the loading technique. Even opening the image locally took some time. Maybe you can transform it to SVG (lots of evenly colored areas) or create several images with different resolutions.

Comment: Well this first thing is already there as you can see. And the second you describe would be that usual Leaflet/Tile image way. Well maybe I have to do it in that way indeed. Thank you anway =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [Loading a huge image (5mb) into svg background leads to pixelation and performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002398/loading-a-huge-image-5mb-into-svg-background-leads-to-pixelation-and-performan) there does not seen to be a solution. Just lower the size and it works in Firefox and Chrome.